# Explore abc module with print function

Tags: python, debugging

We all love debugging python code by print function, arent we? My question is: how to debug abc module from python stdlib? Try to use print function (or sys.stdout file, whatever) and you will end up with an error like

```
TypeError: writeobject with NULL file
```

The reason is kinda obviouse: standart streams are not initilized yet at this point. So how to probe this code?
On top of it, it seams that classes declared here are not built by builtin python3 function `__build_class__`: check out [this code](https://github.com/magniff/magic/blob/master/example.py), it works with "regular" classes and doesnt with abc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you trying to debug a standard module?

Comment: I am trying to understand what is so special about abc module: why my overrided `__build_class__` function is not applied here. abc module by itself works kinda ok

Comment: Open a file and write your log messages into.

Comment: NameError: name 'open' is not defined

Comment: I'am puzzled. If I place a `print 'xyz'` into the first line of the abc-module it will be prined without any exception. I'am unable to emulate your problem. Is there anything special with your python installation?

Comment: i am using python 3, as i mentioned `On top of it, it seams that classes declared here are not built by builtin python3`

Comment: I'am sorry, I should read your question more carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. abc module is actually kind of special: it involved in python bootstrap sequence, so at point you code starts you have fully built and loaded module object. To tinker with abc simply use imp.reload to rebuilt module in runtime.